# How to add jQuery function to all elements with specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a simple code which cycles through list elements adding and removing class "active".
This code works great but only for first list element. What I would like it to do is to apply this same function to all lists with class "imageslider".

Any help is appreciated!

**Here's the js code:**

```
<script>

toggleSlide = function(){
  $(".imageslider li.active").removeClass()
  .next().add(".imageslider li:first").last().addClass("active");
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 500);

</script>
```

**And here's is my HTML markup:**

```
//First list

    <ul class="imageslider">
      <li class="active">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>


//Second list

    <ul class="imageslider">
      <li class="active">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how people are answering this.  The question isn't at all clear.  Can you explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
toggleSlide = function () {
    $(".imageslider").each(function () {
        $(this).find("li.active").removeClass()
            .next().add($(this).children().first()).last().addClass("active");
    })
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 500);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p5XR3/)

Comment: That did the trick! I was playing around with .each() but didn't get it right I guess. The 4th row would have taken even more time to solve with my coding skills. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `:first` predicate!

```
.next().add(".imageslider li").last().addClass("active");
```